# pg_listening_channels() is not returning the channels name

Tags: postgresql-9.2

1) i want to know the channels name which are listing on my database but pg_listening_channels() name always returning null value (blank) even some clients are listening on this database.

below is my pgsql code. is any thing wrong in this code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION query_trigger()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
 send_message  text;
 queryString  text;
 channelNameArray text[];
 channelNames text;
      BEGIN
        queryString = current_query();
        channelNameArray = pg_listening_channels();
        channelNames = array_to_string(channelNameArray , ',');

           send_message := queryString || '  ' || channelNames;
           insert into "Client_Address" values (channelNames , queryString) ;
           PERFORM pg_notify('myChannel', send_message  );
           RETURN NULL;
          END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION query_trigger() OWNER TO postgres;

Schema of Client_Address table
Notify_node   text;
query         text;
```

Answer (score 2):

`pg_listening_channels` reports listens *in your own session*. It won't (and can't) report listens from other sessions.

There's no way to get that information in Pg 9.2 via the system directly. You could always maintain a side-table with the info but you'd have the usual problems with keeping it in sync.

Why do you want to do this anyway? It's kind of bizarre to use `NOTIFY` like this. Why not have everyone listen on the same channel and notify them all with a single call?

Are you attempting to write audit logging? If so consider using one of the existing solutions or just using csv logging.