# How to find the current length of a postgres NOTIFY/LISTEN message queue?

Tags: postgresql, message-queue

Question title says it all. We have TRIGGERS set up on a database table that are being consumed by an offsite worker. However, there are times that it appears the worker falls behind in updating records. Is there a SQL query or call to determine the existing length of the message queue? (without popping any of the items). I see numerous mentions of this queue in the postgres documentation and [other stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087347/what-happens-with-a-notify-when-no-session-has-issued-listen-in-postgresql), but can't find anything regarding actually determining the length. Any help is appreciated!

For those of you familiar with redis, I'm looking for the equivalent of an `LLEN` command for this postgres message queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything which directly reports the number of queue entries.

The closest thing is probably [`pg_notification_queue_usage()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-SESSION-TABLE), which tells you what fraction of the queue storage is currently used (out of 8GB in total in a standard installation, according to the [`NOTIFY` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html#idm46428673420640)).

The memory usage is going to depend a lot on the payload, of course, but if you can figure out your average notification size, you should be able to translate this to an approximate queue length.

Comment: Definitely looks like this is something useful, but unfortunately we're using postgres 9.5. Maybe this can be used to encourage the team to upgrade! Still frustrating that there's no easy way to determine the queue length. Alas.